# how to create and display a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a photo galley, I had added the picture in list and on thumbnail picture click I want to show the big image blurring the background and displayed in the center. I am able to create a dynamic div and display big image but it is always coming below the list. 
Please find my code at following address:  https://github.com/sanjana-1604/BirthDay-.git

Please check my code and let me know what to do to get div properly

Comment: instead of sharing the code in your git, please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so, and share the link of the fiddle with us..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded your code and a had look over it. Although you should have shared a snippet.

I deeply appreciate your effort towards programming.

```js
function changeBackgroundColor(image, image_src, color) {
  if (image === 'no') {
    document.body.style.background = "red";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('Img/bg.png')";
  }
}
var imageCount = 01;
total = 20;

function slide(x) {

  var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
  imageCount = imageCount + x;
  if (imageCount > total) {
    imageCount = 01;
  }
  if (imageCount < 1) {
    imageCount = total;
  }
  image.src = "Img/big_pics" + imageCount + ".jpg";
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////Code Written by me starts here//////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////


window.addEventListener("load", function() { //The code inside this block must be executed only after the complete page is loaded,
  var createBackgroundFader = function(imgNumber) {
    var fader = document.createElement("div");
    fader.classList.add("fader", "hidden");
    fader.id = "bigImageViewer" + imgNumber;

    fader.addEventListener("click", function(event) { //This block of code will enable you to click on the empty space of fader to hide it
      if (event.target === this) {
        this.classList.toggle("hidden");
      }
    });

    return fader;
  };
  var createBigImageViewer = function(imgNumber) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var fader = createBackgroundFader(imgNumber);

    img.classList.add("bigImg");
    img.src = "Img/big_pics/" + imgNumber + ".jpg";

    fader.appendChild(img);

    return fader;
  };
  var createListItem = function(imgNumber) { //In javascript you can create functions like this as well...
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    //Preparing img element
    img.setAttribute("src", "Img/Thumbnail/" + imgNumber + ".jpg");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "thumbnail image");
    img.dataset.imgNumber = imgNumber;
    img.classList.add("image", "thumbnail");
    img.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var bigImageViewer = document.getElementById("bigImageViewer" + this.dataset.imgNumber);
      bigImageViewer.classList.toggle("hidden"); //Look up dictionary to know the meaning of toggle...
    });

    //Appending img element to li
    li.appendChild(img);

    //Lastly return li
    return li;
  };


  var photoList = document.getElementById("photoList");
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    photoList.appendChild(createListItem(i + 1)); //Appending the freshly cooked li element to photoList
    document.body.appendChild(createBigImageViewer(i + 1)); //Appending bigImageViewer to body but you can't see because they are hidden by default. Click on a thumbnail to view the BigImage
  }
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////Code Written by me ends here//////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

```css
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}
/*title "1 year june"*/

.title_h1 {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  /*to make border rounded*/
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
}
/*   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */

/*main menu */

.main_menu
/*main menu*/

{
  list-style-type: none;
  /* to avoid bullets in the list items */
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 20%;
}
.main_menu li {
  display: inline;
  /* to display horizontally */
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* main white div */

.main_div
/*class to draw main div*/

{
  position: absolute;
  /*positioned relative to body*/
  top: 18%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 65%;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#welcome_note {
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  width: 15em;
  height: 16em;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
#welcome_note h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.mainpage_header {
  height: 15em;
  background: #ff8566;
  position: relative;
  /*positioned relative to main div*/
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 80%;
}
#DP_img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
/* @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*/

/*  PHOTO PAGE */

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.Photo_main_div {
  position: absolute;
  /*positioned relative to body*/
  top: 18%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#photo_page_outline {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#photo_page_header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(251, 130, 184);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#photo_page_footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(251, 130, 184);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  clear: both;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#content ul {
  list-style: none;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#content li {
  width: 14em;
  float: left;
}
#content img {
  -webkit-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  filter: blur(3px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#content img:hover {
  -webkit-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  transform: translateZ(25px) rotate(3deg);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////Code Written by me starts here////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

li .thumbnail {
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
}
.fader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
div .bigImg {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  border: solid white 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 10px 30px 50px 0px;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////Code Written by me ends here////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

```html
<!-- No Changes were made in this file except commenting all li elements.

li elements can easily be added to the ul through javascript from inside a loop

Kindly see from line number 80 in javascript to understand the logic.

-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="myJavaScript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS.css">

</head>

<body onload="changeBackgroundColor('yes')">
  <h1 class="title_h1">
            1 year June
        </h1>

  <ul class="main_menu">
    <li><a href="Photos.html">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>Stroy</li>
  </ul>

  <div class=" Photo_main_div">

    <div id="photo_page_outline">
      <div id="content">
        <header id="photo_page_header">
          PHOTOS
        </header>
        <ul id="photoList">
          <!--                        <li onclick="slide(1)"><img src="Img/Thumbnail/1.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image" class = "image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\2.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image" onClick="slide(2)" class = "image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\3.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image" onclick="slide(3)"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\4.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image" onclick="slide(4)"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\5.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\6.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\7.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\8.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\9.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\10.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\11.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\12.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\13.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\14.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\15.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\16.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\17.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\18.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\19.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>
                        <li><img src="Img\Thumbnail\20.jpg" width="200" height = "120" alt="thumbnail image"></li>-->

        </ul>
        <footer id="photo_page_footer">
          My Album
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively you may download the solved project from this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqqktw9y8u97zsf/BirthDay--master.zip?dl=1

I hope this would solve your problem.

Note: In your big_pics folder, kindly change file names from 01.jpg through 09.jpg to 1.jpg through 9.jpg

References:
Read about the following on MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) to more know about how your problem was solved...

1. The 'this' keyword
2. Object Oriented Javascript
3. DOM
4. [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Thanks Pratik, your solution works exactly the way i wanted my code to work.  Can you please let me know the exact issue in my code. I was trying to adjust the z-index for the div, but it was not coming properly.

Comment: Issues with your code:
1. There was no element with an id "image".
2. If you wanted to show a big image, fading everything behind, then you must toggle visibility of the big image viewer with each click on the thumbnail.

I created a class ".hidden" to hide an element. And i am toggling this class on the fader element (which is also the container element of big image viewer). So when you click on a thumbnail it will toggle ".hidden" class on the fader and i have also programmed that when you click anywhere outside the big image viewer the ".hidden" class s toggled again on the fader element.

Comment: Read the code written by me line by line and follow the sequence by which i am calling the functions. Do a search if you don't understand something, for example you may search for document.createElement() and read its documentation.

Read documentations on MDN (Mozilla Developer Network), they are one of the best. Try out example they share and you will eventually make your way through it.

This is the exact way I learned, when I started to program :)